# HttpClient - Header with non-ascii Characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ascii, dotnet-httpclient

I have a simple `asp.net core` app that sends `HttpRequest` with custom header for username.
The `username` header value type is `UTF-8` string.

The problem is that whenever this string contains non-ascii characters, an exception 'Request headers must contain only ASCII chatacters' is thrown (see image below).
Is there away to bypass this?

Thank you
[image: non-ascii header exception]

Comment: As a heads-up, the question that is **already answered** is for Java, not C#, like this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the below

```
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
...
Uri.EscapeDataString(Records)
```